# Pinned reference to FFI object consumed by calling methods that receive it

Tags: rust, ffi, rust-pin

I'm writing a foreign function interface (ffi) to expose the API of a pre-existing C++ library to some new Rust code I am writing. I am using the Rust [`cxx`](https://cxx.rs/) module for this.

I am running into some problems related to `Pin` (a topic which I have to admit I don't have a complete grasp of).

My C++ module has an API that exposes pointers to some contained objects from the main object that owns these contained objects. Here is a contrived example:

```cpp
// test.hpp
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class Row {
    std::string row_data;
public:
    void set_value(const std::string& new_value) {
        this->row_data = new_value;
    }
};

class Table {
    Row row;
public:
    Table() : row() {};
    Row* get_row() {
        return &this->row;
    }

};

inline std::unique_ptr<Table> make_table() {
    return std::make_unique<Table>();
}
```

The idea is that you create a `Table` object, which then allows you to obtain a pointer to it's `Row` so you can manipulate it.

My attempt to create a Rust FFI looks like this:

```rust
// main.rs
use std::pin::Pin;

use cxx::let_cxx_string;


#[cxx::bridge]
mod ffi {

    unsafe extern "C++" {
        include!("src/test.hpp");

        type Table;

        pub fn make_table() -> UniquePtr<Table>;

        fn get_row(self: Pin<&mut Table>) -> *mut Row;

        type Row;

        pub fn set_value(self: Pin<&mut Row>, value: &CxxString);
    }
}

impl ffi::Table {
    pub fn get_row_ref<'a>(self: Pin<&'a mut ffi::Table>) -> Pin<&'a mut ffi::Row> {
        unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(&mut *self.get_row()) }
    }
}

fn main() {

    let mut table = ffi::make_table();

    let row = table.pin_mut().get_row_ref();

    let_cxx_string!(hello="hello world");
    
    row.set_value(&hello);
    
    let_cxx_string!(hello2="bye world");
    row.set_value(&hello2);


}
```

Note that:

- The `cxx` module requires that non-const C++ methods take `Pin<&mut T>` as their receiver
- The C++ `get_row` method returns a pointer, which I want to convert into a reference to the Row which has the same lifetime as the owning `Table` object - that's what the `get_row_ref` wrapper is for.

I have two problems:

1. Is it sound for me to call [`Pin::new_unchecked`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#method.new_unchecked) here? The documentation implies it is not:

   > calling Pin::new_unchecked on an &'a mut T is unsafe because while you are
   > able to pin it for the given lifetime 'a, you have no control over whether
   > it is kept pinned once 'a ends

   If that is not safe, how do I proceed?
2. This program fails to compile with the following error:

   ```
   error[E0382]: use of moved value: `row`
     --> src/main.rs:41:2
      |
   34 |     let row = table.pin_mut().get_row_ref();
      |         --- move occurs because `row` has type `Pin<&mut Row>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   ...
   38 |     row.set_value(&hello);
      |     --- value moved here
   ...
   41 |     row.set_value(&hello2);
      |     ^^^ value used here after move
   ```

   The first call to `set_value` consumes the pinned reference, and after that it can't
   be used again. `&mut T` is not `Copy`, so `Pin<&mut Row>` is not `Copy` either.

   How do I set up the API so that the reference to `Row` can be used for multiple
   successive method calls (within the constraints established by `cxx`)?

For those wanting to try it out:

```
# Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
cxx = "1.0.52"

[build-dependencies]
cxx-build = "1.0"
```

```
// build.rs
fn main() {
    cxx_build::bridge("src/main.rs")
        .flag("-std=c++17")
        .include(".")
        .compile("test");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Is it sound for me to call [`Pin::new_unchecked`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#method.new_unchecked) here?

Yes, it's sound. In this context, we know the `Row` is pinned because:

1. The `Table` is pinned;
2. The `Row` is stored inline in the `Table`;
3. C++'s move semantics essentially means every C++ object is "pinned" anyway.

> 2. This program fails to compile with the following error:

When you call a method on a normal mutable reference (`&mut T`), the compiler implicitly performs a *reborrow* in order to avoid moving the mutable reference, because `&mut T` is not `Copy`. Unfortunately, this compiler "magic" doesn't extend to `Pin<&mut T>` (which is not `Copy` either), so instead we must reborrow explicitly.

The easiest way to reborrow is to use [`Pin::as_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#method.as_mut). This use case is even called out in the documentation:

> This method is useful when doing multiple calls to functions that consume the pinned type.

```
fn main() {
    let mut table = ffi::make_table();

    let mut row = table.pin_mut().get_row_ref();

    let_cxx_string!(hello="hello world");
    row.as_mut().set_value(&hello);

    let_cxx_string!(hello2="bye world");
    row.as_mut().set_value(&hello2);
}
```

The use of `as_mut()` on the last use of `row` is not strictly necessary, but applying it consistently is probably clearer. When compiled with optimizations, this function is probably a noop anyway (for `Pin<&mut T>`).

> How do I set up the API so that the reference to `Row` can be used for multiple successive method calls (within the constraints established by `cxx`)?

If you want to hide the `as_mut()`'s, you could add a method that accepts a `&mut Pin<&mut ffi::Row>` and does the `as_mut()` call. (Note that `as_mut()` is defined on `&mut Pin<P>`, so the compiler will insert a reborrow of the outer `&mut`.) Yes, this means there are now two levels of indirection.

```
impl ffi::Row {
    pub fn set_value2(self: &mut Pin<&mut ffi::Row>, value: &cxx::CxxString) {
        self.as_mut().set_value(value)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut table = ffi::make_table();

    let mut row = table.pin_mut().get_row_ref();

    let_cxx_string!(hello="hello world");
    row.set_value2(&hello);

    let_cxx_string!(hello2="bye world");
    row.set_value2(&hello2);
}
```